# Data memory barrier(DMB) instruction does block cores in ARM multicore architecture?

Tags: assembly, arm, multicore, memory-barriers, barrier

I read memory barrier in ARM architecture reference manual, and I saw the data memory barrier (DMB) instruction.

My question is does DMB instruction(especially 'dmb ish') block cores?

For example, quad-core architecture (core 0-3), core 0 executes DMB instruction, then other core blocked until some kinds of barrier execution flow (control flow such as core-cache controller-memory controller)?

Or does the dmb instruction have nothing to do with these parts at all?

In the ARM reference manual(https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0802/a/A32-and-T32-Instructions/DMB--DSB--and-ISB), DMB instruction does not affect other instructions execution except memory access (ld, st). But I'm curious about this part.

**So clearly, 'dmb ish' never affect other core's execution?**

Comment: The architecture reference manual only documents the observable architectural effects of the instruction, not its performance characteristics or how it might or might not be implemented on a chip.  When you say "block cores", what exact observable effects do you have in mind?  Is there a particular piece of code whose behavior you would expect to be different depending on the answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

It has no visible effect on instruction execution; but enormous effect on data read from or written to memory subsystems by those instructions. And very visible effects on how quickly those instructions execute

As Nate Eldridge points out, the architecture manual describes the effect of those instructions without describing the implementation, which may vary dramatically between various ARM chips.

Things that you might expect from a particular implementation:

- That each core be forced to drive its' cache synchronization engine to a checkpoint, potentially stalling other cores for hundreds of CPU cycles.
- That instruction decode queues might stall, or be discarded entirely.
- That other cores' L1 caches might be partly or completely invalidated, causing a significant performance penalty to  other cores.

On systems with multiple CPU chips, where synchronization has to synchronize L2 cache between chips, the results would be correspondingly more expensive.

Comment: Do you have any sources to support the idea that waiting for load to happen and stores to commit on this core could lead to stalls on other cores, or invalidating L1 on other cores?  `dmb ish` should just be like `mfence` on x86, purely local to one core.  So the effects on other cores are limited to sending the RFO (read-for-ownership) requests for any pending stores, which will indeed invalidate some lines in L1 of other cores.  Are you talking about `dmb sy` which might have to be more intrusive to sync with caches that aren't part of the same coherency domain?

Comment: Also, what kind of "checkpoint" are you talking about for other cores?  The docs for DSB and DMB (https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0802/a/A32-and-T32-Instructions/DMB--DSB--and-ISB) don't say anything about ordering operations outside the core executing the instruction.

Answer (score -1):

DMB only affects the order of instructions in the currently running thread. For anything synchronizing cross-thread and cross-core you need some higher level primitive such as a semaphore or a mutex (and normally some OS support to handle it efficiently).